# What is the difference between compound words and derivational words?

Tags: grammar, morphology, compounds

I know that compound words are made up with two small words, but is "tax-free" or "timeless" compound word? How about "thought-free"?

Comment: Compound words consist of two (or sometimes more) smaller bases. "Tax-free" is a compound adjective, as is "thought-free". "Less" is a suffix, not a base, so "timeless" is not a compound word. The suffix "less" attaches to the noun "time" to give an adjective with the meaning "without ~ / having no ~".

Comment: @BillJ Is it really that straightforward, though? How do you determine that _-free_ here is a base rather than a derivational suffix. The stress pattern in _tax-free_ (to me at least) matches that of _taxless_, not that of _tax-based_, which would argue against compound status.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That's what I was confused about too! only "thought-free" can be a compound word right?

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply!  May I ask one more question? what do we call the words separately like in "thought-free"? Is it called free word?

Comment: @ronghe It's comparable to the syntactic construction where the adjective has a following PP as complement, cf. "free of tax". I can't see any reason not to call it a compound. Other similar compounds include "cholesterol-free", "burglar-proof" and "oil-rich".

Comment: @BillJ Just curious, how would you analyze *strawberry*?

Comment: @AlexB. I'd analyse it as a compound: "straw-berry".

Comment: @BillJ of course but I wanted to see your argumentation though.

Comment: @BillJ what I’m trying to say is that, on the one hand, you’ll have compounds like strawberry, blackberry, etc., and, on the other hand, words like mulberry, raspberry, etc. And then you have goose1 (a bird) and goose2 (meaning?) as in gooseberry.

Comment: There is no difficulty in recognising them as compounds even though the meaning of the whole is not predictable from those of the compound bases -- it is enough that the second base is formally and semantically identifiable with the berry that occurs as a separate word, or in semantically more transparent compounds like black.berry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A lot depends on your theory of morphology - see e.g. [Lieber and Štekauer 2011](https://www.oxfordhandbooks.com/view/10.1093/oxfordhb/9780199695720.001.0001/oxfordhb-9780199695720-e-1) - see esp. **1.1.4 Summary**. Several tests for compounding have been proposed; the biggest problem is that they do not necessarily yield the same results. And then there is no clear-cut, universal boundary between a free word-form and a bound affix. As to be expected, by its very nature, no single theory can encompass all language data into its procrustean bed.

That being said, [Bauer, Lieber and Plag 2013](https://www.oxfordscholarship.com/view/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780198747062.001.0001/acprof-9780198747062-chapter-17), in *The Oxford Reference Guide to English Morphology*, write the following:

"The semantically related formations involving -*free* and *ill*- are sometimes treated as affixes or affixoids, but we consider formations with these elements as compounds, on the grounds that there are no compelling arguments for their status as affixes or affixoids (see Chapter 16 and [Dalton-Puffer and Plag (2000)](https://www.degruyter.com/view/journals/flin/34/3-4/article-p225.xml) for pertinent tests" (p. 354).

Comment: Thank you for your reply!

Comment: @Alex B. Right observation in 1.1.4 summary.

Answer (score -2):

This question is likely based on the assumption that *less* is a proper word that can compound, and thus drrives the morpheme. At least, that was my first impulse to counter @BillJ's comment.

However, similar to *most* and *-most*, the morphemes are likely not the same, though historically entangled (cf. wiki/[-most](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-most)).

> From Middle English *-les, -leas,* from Old English *-lēas* (“-less”), from lēas (“devoid of, loose from, false”), from Proto-Germanic *lausaz (“loose”). (**Not related to *less***, which derives from *laisiz, *laisizô.)
>
> [wiki/[-less](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-less); emphasis mine).

I wouldn't say its not related at all, if a plausible connection might be too distant. But note the different umlaut anyway: *laus- and *lais-.

It figures that the pronounciation differs, to say the least: whereas *-free* has stress, that's not the case for *-less*. The vowel therefore differs from that in *less*.

Hence, it's debatable whether language acquisition has them as one stem, or if the association, that invariably exists, is more difficult than straight up derivation would be.

Point in case, the written form likely confuses us. At least a second language speaker learning reading and listening in parallel will be confused by a comparison with *-ful*--with a single *l*--that I see now however in a difficult cluster with German *gefallen*, *Gefühl*, but not--to be contrarian--not with *full*, as if *full of awe*. It's more complicated than that, and certainly we can observe that *-ly* as a suffix would be there for a learner--not so much for the current historian--to consider for comparison.

All that doesn't exclude that some speakers have this, who are not bound by historic analysis, and operate from a less than absolute synchronic analysis. But only in English, whereas German has  e.g. *arbeitslos* (workless, "unemployed"), where *los* rather seems to correspond to adj. *lose* "loose", not "lose"; or to *los*, *was ist los?* "what's going off?", *los gehen*, "let's go" (a radio dj once mistranslated "equal it goes loose", i.e. *gleich geht's los*).